# Karma-Coverage produces (node) warning: possible EventEmitter memory leak detected

Tags: node.js, typescript, karma-runner

I am getting the following warning:

```
    (node) warning: possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 close listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit.
Trace
    at Server.addListener (events.js:239:17)
    at Server.once (events.js:265:8)
    at Server.close (net.js:1473:12)
    at ...
```

This occurs when i added coverage to my karma.config.js file

```
config.set({
    preprocessors: {    
        'src/*/*.ts': ['coverage'],
    }
 }
```

I'm using Node.js version 5.0.
Please help.

Comment: Are you using electron by any chance?